# JAVA date is shifted by one day in production machines

Tags: java, jquery, spring, jsp

I have a java spring mvc project with JSP where I manipulate the dates using "jQuery datetimepicker", the problem is that locally the dates are recorded correctly, but in production the dates are always shifted by one day, i check the timezonne using `TimeZone.getDefault()`, it's the same as my local machine, if anyone has any idea to check

Code JSP :

```
<div class='col-lg-12'>
    <div class='form-group'>
        <fmt:formatDate pattern="dd-MM-yyyy" value="${child.dateNaissance}" var="myDateVar"/>
                                            <input type="text" id="myDatepicker${status.index}" class='form-control date_input'  required="required"
                                                        name='parent.enfants[${status.index}].dateNaissance' value='${myDateVar}'
                                                        placeholder="Date de naissance* (JJ-MM-AAAA)" >
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
```

JQUERY :

```
(function($) {
var today = new Date();
var lastDate = new Date(today.getFullYear(), 11, 31);
var defaultDate = new Date();
defaultDate.setMonth(defaultDate.getMonth() - 30);
var minimumDate = new Date();
minimumDate.setFullYear(minimumDate.getFullYear() - 18);

var datePickerOptions = {
        todayHighlight: true,
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showOtherMonths: true,
        selectOtherMonths: true,
        minDate : minimumDate,
        yearRange: "-21:+0",
        maxDate: defaultDate,
        dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
        closeText: "Fermer",
        prevText: "Précédent",
        nextText: "Suivant",
        currentText: "Aujourd'hui",
        monthNames: ["janvier", "février", "mars", "avril", "mai", "juin",
          "juillet", "août", "septembre", "octobre", "novembre", "décembre"
        ],
        monthNamesShort: ["janv.", "févr.", "mars", "avr.", "mai", "juin",
          "juil.", "août", "sept.", "oct.", "nov.", "déc."
        ],
        dayNames: ["dimanche", "lundi", "mardi", "mercredi", "jeudi", "vendredi", "samedi"],
        dayNamesShort: ["dim.", "lun.", "mar.", "mer.", "jeu.", "ven.", "sam."],
        dayNamesMin: ["D", "L", "M", "M", "J", "V", "S"],

        beforeShow : function() {
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('.ui-datepicker').css('z-index', 99999999999999);
                $('.ui-datepicker').css('position', 'absolute');

            }, 0);
        }
    };
$(document)
        .ready(
                function() {
                     $(".birthdayDatePicker").datepicker(datePickerOptions);
                });
```

})(jQuery);

CODE Java :

```
    /**
 * Binding de la date en format standard
 * 
 * @param binder Binder
 */
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    dateFormat.setLenient(false);
    CustomDateEditor editor = new CustomDateEditor(dateFormat, true);
    binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, editor);
}
```

Entity :

```
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy")
private Date dateNaissance;
```

Comment: More details are required. How do you parse the date-time that comes as a request parameter? What class do you use (`ZonedDateTime`, `Instant`, e.g.). Please, provide some code snippets

Comment: write the code you are using

Comment: @Ofek  I added some code, only to know this behavior concerns the whole application

Comment: @SemyonKirekov  sorry for the delay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that the problem is about `SimpleDateFormat`. The pattern contains no timezone - `dd-MM-yyyy`. The date passed as the parameter does not necessarily have the same time zone as the server does. That's why you may face conversion issues.

I consider you should use something like `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME` as a format pattern.

P.S. `java.util.Date` is not recommended to use anymore. Take a look at `java.time.ZonedDateTime`.